# MySQL float ids for nested list?

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

My database looks like below:

- id
- email
- message

I can list the rows with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

However, I want to list them nested, like below:

```
my_name
my_message

  another_name
  another_message

  new_name
  new_message

some_name
some_message
```

With normal ids it would look like below:

```
1
  3
  4
2
```

The SQL is not aware of the nesting. I could use a `parent_id` which is quite common. However, it's quite tricky to get right with pagination etc.

An idea I have is to use `float` on the ids instead. Then it would look like below:

```
1
  1.1
  1.2
2
  2.1
  2.2
```

The SQL will make the order correct without hassle and a pagination would be easy as well.

**Is there any pitfalls with the float approach? I've never seen anyone use it.**

Comment: That is quite a big difficult to grasp at first but see http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: *An idea I have is to use float on the ids instead.* Extremely bad idea. Use non-precise values? 1.1 may occur something like 1.000000000000099... Think, for example, about fully qualified node path. 1 -> 1/1 -> 1/1/1 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way, using `DECIMAL` would be a way of doing this without risk of rounding anomalies as mentioned in the comment from Akina above.

The pitfall is that you can only simulate two level with a scaled number like this. What if you want a third level like 1.1.3? How would you make that different from 1.13, the thirteenth direct child under 1.?

It's better to use the `parent_id` solution if you want to support hierarchies in a normalized way, without limiting yourself to two levels.

You could also use a variety of other solutions to simulate hierarchies. The comment about using a node path in a string is one option: `1/1/3`. There are other solutions. You might like my answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)

Comment: Thanks! I've not made up my mind of depth yet, but I probably only need one level so DECIMAL may be the way to go for me. Else I also like the node path idea.